# Return last not null value before nan occurrences

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a series 's' with null and not null values:

```
s = pd.Series([np.nan, 5, 4, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 4, 3, np.nan])
```

I need to obtain 's1' returned last not null value before each np.nan:

```
s1 = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3, np.nan]
```

Many thanks in advance.

Regards
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create a grouper using `Series.isna` + `Series.cumsum` to identify continuous blocks of non `NaN` values, then `groupby` the series on this grouper and `transform` using `last` finally mask the values which are `duplicated` in the grouper:

```
g = s.isna().cumsum()
s1 = s.groupby(g).transform('last').mask(g.duplicated(keep='last'))
```

Result:

```
print(s1)

0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    2.0
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    NaN
7    3.0
8    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s1 = []
for i in range(len(s)-1):
    if s[i+1] == np.nan:
        s1.append(s[i])
```

Comment: Please include a brief description of your code with your answers

Answer (score 0):

Taking a cue from @ShubamSharma's answer, get the rows that are null, convert to type `int`, get the difference between 1 and 0, working your way from the bottom (since we are looking for the last non null value before nan), and finally use `np.where` to get our result:

```
s1 = np.where(s.isna().astype(int).diff(-1).eq(-1), s, np.nan)
s1
array([nan, nan, nan,  2., nan, nan, nan,  3., nan])
```